# How to get an java.lang.Class of a scala object for an annotation argument

Tags: scala

I have an object and I need to pass its class to an annotation that takes java.lang.Class, eg:

```
public @interface PrepareForTest {
   Class<?>[] value()
}

object MyObject

@PrepareForTest(Array(?????))
class MySpec ...
```

I've tried:

```
@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[MyObject]))
// error: not found: type MyObject

@PrepareForTest(Array(MyObject))
// error: type mismatch
// found: MyObject.type (with underlying type object MyObject
// required: java.lang.Class[_]

@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[MyObject.type]))
// error: class type required by MyObject.type found
```

Not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classOf[MyObject$]` does not work because there is no type called `MyObject$`.

In fact, the issue did come up before and there is no easy solution. See the discussion on https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2453#comment:5

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `throws` annotation:

```
@throws(classOf[IOException])
```

The annotation itself is declared as:

```
class throws(clazz: Class[_]) extends StaticAnnotation
```

Doing the same for an `object` does not seem to be possible because scala seems to prevent an object from being viewed as having a class in its own right